# Character Encoding - Incorrect Display?

Tags: html, wordpress, encoding

So I have a pretty fresh WordPress installation and am working on a custom theme. I have noticed that special characters aren't displaying properly.

At the moment if I try and use a ' or a "" it is displaying as an í.

I have the character encoding set to UTF-8 in my header and also the browser. I have tried in two browsers and it is the same. If I view the page source it is displaying the correct code for an apostrophe.

If I use the FireFox developer tools and manually edit the HTML and add a " or ' in to the text then it displays this correctly.

I have checked the database and the ' or " is showing correctly in there and the database is set as utf-general.

The page in question so you can see what I mean:

http://dev.evaske.com/Liverpool/about-us-2/

Any ideas what else I can try?

EDIT:

So I've managed to get it down to the fact that cause it's font-face, it doesn't like the fact that WP is outputting the ’. Is there a way to make it so that this isn't happening and it just pulls the "" instead of ’?

Comment: Save your sourcecode as UTF-8 encoded. most text editors still have ANSI as default.

Comment: Espresso 2 is already set to save them in UTF-8 and then the text I'm actually inputting to show is from WordPress. View http://dev.evaske.com/Liverpool/about-us-2/ - The first "Test's" is from WP generated text and the second one is hard coded in to the PHP file. It appears that WP is outputting "&#8217;" if you view the source code but that isn't what is in the database.